# Can I change the language the Xcode creates playgrounds in?

Tags: c++, xcode

Can I change the programming language that Xcode create playgrounds in? I find it a bit annoying that I have to create new projects If I want to test C or C++ code.

I can't seem to find anything about this.

Comment: I thought the Playground was just for Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode playground is just for Swift, but you can use SoloLearn's C/C++ playground: https://code.sololearn.com/cHerGNWry1nb/#c

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that this was going to be the case.